# Please solve this jQuery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and PHP. I tried myself, but don't understand how to get below output. Please would someone look into this?

**I am trying to achieve this:** `http://jsfiddle.net/exttq/`

I mean: Form1 and Form2 are displaying before only, BUT i shud open or close them only after when I check or uncheck the boxes

What's wrong in this PHP function code?

```
function eshop_extras_checkout($echo){


    $echo .= '

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

    <script>

    $(".formGroup").hide();
    $("#chooseForm input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
        }
        else {
            $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
        }
    });
    ​
</script>';

    $echo .= '<fieldset class="eshop eshop_extra">' . "\n";


    $echo .= ' <form id="chooseForm">
        <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form1"> Form1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form2"> Form2<br>
    </form>

    <form id="form1" class="formGroup">
        <h2>FORM 1</h2>
        <label>Name</label><input type="text"> <br>
        <label>Address</label><input type="text">
    </form>

    <form id="form2" class="formGroup">
        <h2>FORM 2</h2>
        <label>Username</label><input type="text"> <br>
    </form>';


    $echo .= '<legend>Articles Order Form</legend>' . "\n";



    return $echo;
}
```

Comment: What's the PHP code meant to do? What does it actually do when you run it?

Comment: Also, check your Javascript console to see if you have any errors.

Comment: "*What's wrong in this PHP function code?*" that you have to specify on your own. We indeed can't do it without knowing what actually you're trying to achieve. Please be more specific.

Comment: -1 for excruciatingly vague question and generic title.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what isn't working and what have you done to attempt to resolve this?

Comment: Iam asking, the above code should work functionality like this: http://jsfiddle.net/exttq/

The only diff is: my query is combined php and jquery (instead of just query)

Comment: I mean: Form1 and Form2 are displaying before only, BUT i shud open or close them only after when I check or uncheck the boxes...

Answer (score 1):

First thing I observed is that your Script is before the HTML in your DOM .. I suggest you put that in DOM Ready Handler and try again..

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".formGroup").hide();
       $("body").on("change","#chooseForm input:checkbox" ,function() {
           if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
            }
            else {
              $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
           }
       });
   });
</script>'
```

Comment: Hey, I tried like this too, BUT not working...  I mean: Form1 and Form2 are displaying before only, BUT i shud open or close them only after when I check or uncheck the boxes...

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this example..??

Comment: Also try delegating the event as I did for the checkboxes ...

Comment: I am trying to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/exttq/  (BUT trying into my PHP code)..